# Spring Security 3 with LDAP and TokenBasedRememberMeServices

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm trying to use TokenBasedRememeberMe. Works like a champ for internally managed users, but users managed through AD with LDAP systems fail.

I found this post from 2009 where it sounds to me like it's not a supported thing. http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?77821-Spring-Security-3-0-Remember-me-Token-based-not-working

Am I right in saying that --- is that a combination that is not supported by Spring Security?

aaron

Comment: Please correct the link. It's a 404.

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't work out fo the box. `TokenBasedRememberMeServices` requires access to the user's password which you don't have with AD.

If you read [the manual chapter on remember-me](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#remember-me) it explains that you need a `UserDetailsService` for it to work and explains that you don't normally have one if you are using LDAP. Technically the information returned does not have to contain the password, just some secret and un-guessable information for each user which can be hashed into the token and checked when verifying it.

Alternatively, you can use the "persistent" remember-me option which doesn't require the password. You will still need to provide a `UserDetailsService` implementation though.